# Swift - Sprite kit object in a single view applicationf

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, viewcontroller

I know that it is possible to integrate Sprite kit to a single view application but I want to know I if it is possible to create a object in sprite kit file and then put that on a view? Do I have to set the view class to be SpriteKit class in order to have the object? Thanks!

Comment: what do you want????

Comment: I want a 3d cube that will do stuff base on gestures.

Comment: you can use a 3d cube without sprite kit

Comment: you can also do Gestures with a Sprite Kit game project

Comment: Oh, ok. Do you guys know how? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`SKScene` is attached to `SKView` which is just a `UIView` object. You can even put spritekit content in your SVA via storyboard. Or, you can put UIKit content in you SK app via the `SKView` property in your GameViewController or, via the `self.view` property in your GameScene.